# Issue with Angular 2 form model being undefined despite having being instantiated explicitely

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-forms

I am trying to get an Angular 2 form to work with deeply nested properties.

Here is the ngModel causing trouble:

```
[(ngModel)]="signupForm.userAccount.firstName"
```

I get the following exception when my component/form loads:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined
```

Here is my component definition:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app/signup/signup.component.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, NgClass],
    pipes: [TranslatePipe]
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {

    signupForm:SignupForm;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.signupForm = new SignupForm(new UserAccount());
    }
    ...
```

and my `SignupForm` model:

```
export class SignupForm {

    constructor(userAccount:UserAccount) {
        this.userAccount = userAccount;
    }

    userAccount:UserAccount;
    plainPassword:string;
    placeId:string;
}
```

and finally my `UserAccount` model:

```
export class UserAccount {

    constructor() {
    }

    id:number;
    email:string;
    password:string;
    firstName:string;
    address:Address;
    token:string;
    emailNotification:boolean;
    lastConnectionDate:Date;
}
```

I am not sure what is going wrong as I take care to instantiate my model (`SignupForm` and `UserAccount`) from my `ngOnInit` function...

Can someone please help?

**edit**:

I tried as follows:

```
constructor() {
    this.signupForm = new SignupForm(new UserAccount());
}
```

I get the same error...

Comment: rats... ok.  The error message suggests that signupForm.userAccount is undefined at the time ngModel is trying to bind to firstName.  It looks like you're instantiating it correctly, though.

Maybe set a breakpoint in the constructor and see if the error occurs before or after signupForm gets instantiated.  Then check the value of signupForm after the new call.

Comment: Upon verification, the error occurs **after** `signupForm` is instantiated. Which is odd...

Comment: What do you mean by "the new call"?

Comment: I can't reproduce.  This plunker works: http://plnkr.co/edit/sQtAkoV4Tv1CQyiLidao?p=preview

Comment: Umm... Interesting. I am puzzled. The only difference I can think of, is that I use the router and not a tag in order to use/display the component.

Comment: In the plnkr you have all classes in one component. Do you have the same or are the classes separated? if so are you importing them...

Comment: The classes are separated and I am importing them.